# Logistic regression for insurance data with a lot of zeros

Tags: logistic, r-squared, zero-inflation

I have a dataset of insurance claims with a variable $Claim$ is a Binary random variable (i.e. $Claim = 1$ if there is a claim and $Claim = 0$ otherwise). About 95% of the observation has $Claim = 0$

I want to model the Probability of claim: $P(Claim = 1)$.

I tried to use **logistics regression** but get a model with a very low $pseudo$-$R^2$ (about 5-10%). Moreover, normal logistics regression seems not to be a wise choice when there is a very large number of 0 in the data.

Could you please recommend me some ideas of which model other than logistics regression to predict the probability of the outcome, especially when there is a lot of $0$ in the data ? Or, is there any way to enhance the power of prediction of the logistics regression ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: A low pseudo-$R^2$ is not necessarily a cause for concern, it may just be that your data is not easily modeled. Why should logistic regression not be a wise choice if there are many zeros?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should be aware that the "Psuedo-$R^2$" probably doesn't mean what you think it means. In OLS $R^2$ tells you the "percent of variance" that is being explained by the model, but in a logit model you aren't explaining variance at all - you are predicting $Pr(Y=1)$, so there is no direct analogy. Despite that, there are a bunch of different diagnostics for logit models that people call "$R^2$"'s for some reason. For example, Stata provides the "McFadden" $R^2$, which basically tells you how much the model you have specified improves the (log)likelihood compared to a "null" model with no predictors. I'm not sure what particular "logit $R^2$" your program is using, but my experience is that most people do not put a lot of stock in the value of any of these diagnostics as a measure of how "good" the logit model is.

Secondly, and unrelated to the whole $R^2$ issue, you are correct that logit models can sometimes have problems modeling "rare" events. Often this is because the rarity of the event causes N issues. If you have a dataset of 500 people, but 95% of the observations are $Y=0$ then you only have 25 cases where $Y=1$, which inhibits your statistical power for trying to predict Y. So in general, your model is probably going to have an elevated level of type 2 error - you might fail to identify a significant predictor of Y even if it is "really" related to Y.

King and Zeng wrote a highly cited paper outlining these issues and recommending various solutions and adjustments to address these issues

https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/political-analysis/article/logistic-regression-in-rare-events-data/1E09F0F36F89DF12A823130FDF0DA462

However, note that that many of the "solutions" they advocate involve different strategies for **data collection** (e.g. oversampling groups that are likely to have $Y=1$) rather than statistical adjustments. That is, because one of the biggest problems of rare outcomes for logit is simply a lack of N, the ideal solution is to make sure you have enough observations. But if you are stuck with the data you have already, then there is only so much you can do.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Could you please recommend my some criteria that we use to evaluate the goodness of the logistic regression other than $pseudo$ $R^2$ ?Can $RMSE$ be a candidate ? Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. In the areas I work in we tend not to make use of goodness of fit criteria for model selection at all. Rather we use theory and past literature to come up with a model specification, we run that model and then report the results, regardless of whether it's good or not. One of the worries of using tests to decide on model specification is that you can end up unintentionally "p hacking" your data. That being said, I know goodness of fit tests are useful in some contexts, but I'm just not an expert on them because I don't tend to use them very much.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. In fact, this model is a part of my master thesis. I want to model the data as closely as possible. For now, I can't come up with another solution other than logistic regression. All the criteria I used indicate that this model is not so good (I have used some other criteria like $ROC$ curve, accompanied with some statistics test of goodness of fit). Do you think it is a good idea to put this part in the thesis anyway ? or should I erase this model and try to find another appropriate model (but the chance that I will find one is slim). Thank you!

Comment: There are many things to consider, but without knowing any more specifics my personal opinion is that you should still use a logit model, but acknowledge that the coefficients may be downwardly biased due to the rarity of your outcome. Just because a model is "bad" from a goodness of fit perspective doesn't mean it's not worth presenting -  a bad GOF test is just telling you that the variables you have included don't go a good job of predicting the outcome. That could be an accurate description of reality and an important result!